# How to pass variable from controller to javascript after the variable is done being computed?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a button that links to a method, let's call it "method", inside the UserController that looks something like this:

```
def method
  ***do stuff***
  @my_variable = value dependent on the do stuff part
end
```

Is there any way to access the variable in my javascript when it is done being computed (basically, when it's defined)?

Comment: You might want to checkout the Gon gem: https://github.com/gazay/gon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your erb file

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.MyVariable = '<%= @my_variable %>';
<% end %>
```

railscast
http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

Comment: `window.MyVariable = <%= @my_variable.to_json %>;`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use window. solution, here's a different idea to try.

This is what I do in my show.html.erb to pass a reverse geocoded address to map the point in a js function that uses google map API.

```
<!-- Must be set to pass instance vars to javascript -->
<%= javascript_tag "var js_marker_lat = #{@location.latitude.to_json};" %>
<%= javascript_tag "var js_marker_lng = #{@location.longitude.to_json};" %>
```

In the javascript function, you use the vars as usual.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(js_marker_lat, js_marker_lng);
```

In the controller, javascript_tag helper is not available, so you may be limited to to using the html.erb files for js vars stuff.
Please let me know how it goes.